# Finding all variables in a model instead of defining in an array

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently running a gridview which exports to CSV.

The problem is I'm defining it like this. We are going to have custom variables grabbing names so the headers will change, so I'm trying to automate it to grab everything.

```
 // $headers = array(
        //     'Forename',
        //     'Surname',
        //     'user.email',
        //     'user.telephone',
        //     'user.company',
        //     'user.company_role',
        //     'event.name',
        //     'status_id',
        //     'checkin_status_id',
        //     'Question1',
        //     'Question2',
        //     'Question3',
        //     'Question4',
        //     'Question5',
        //     'Question6',

        // );
$row = array();
        foreach($headers as $header) {
            $row[] = EventAttendees::model()->getAttributeLabel($header);
        }
        fputcsv($fp,$row);
```

And I was trying to automate it to grab everything, I tried this

```
$models = EventAttendees::model()->findAll();
        $headers = CHtml::listData($models);
        $row = array();
        foreach($headers as $header) {
            $row[] = EventAttendees::model()->getAttributeLabel($header);
        }
        fputcsv($fp,$row);
```

but it's bringing up a 500 error.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail

Answer (score 0):

`CHtml::listData()` [requires](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) at least 3 parameters specified. You have passed only the first one

Comment: The problem is I want to avoid passing through any parameters and for it to grab everything and findAll is no use.

Comment: Your code is missing one thing. Namely the name of the attribute of "EventAttendees" model where you store the header names.